# How to animate recyclerview on scroll like Google plus/Google newsstand?

Tags: android, scroll, android-animation, android-recyclerview

How do I animate the `RecyclerView` when the items appear for first time and also when the user scrolls, just like the way it works for the google plus app or the google news stand app.

Also I read somewhere that `RecyclerView` does not directly support animation when the user scrolls; if this is true, is there any way we can still do it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I did it this way. Might help someone. I don't know whether it's the best way to do it but works fine for me.

**UPDATE:** 
To fix fast scrolling behaviour, override `onViewDetachedFromWindow` method of the adapter and call `clearAnimation` on the animated view (in this case, `holder.itemView.clearAnimation()` ).Like this:

```
 @Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    holder.itemView.clearAnimation();
}
```

`up_from_bottom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

`down_from_top.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

And finally put this code in `onBindViewHolder` of `recyclerView`. Create a field called lastPosition and initialize it to -1.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;
```

Comment: Is there any way to handle scroll fast it get messed up

Comment: @naiyu Sorry no idea about that.

Comment: To fix fast scrolling behaviour, implement `onViewDetachedFromWindow` on the adapter and call `clearAnimation` on the animated view (in your case, `holder.itemView`).

Comment: It works ..But not in properly when we use it with lazy loading..
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: It's work! I faced a small problem with infinite scroll. Solving by not running the animation in the first position.

Comment: When fragment loads, all the items in the RecyclerView appear at once, rather than one at a time (except when scrolling)
How can I make all my items in the RecyclerView appear one by one?

Comment: Can you please post the Full code snippet. I have no idea where any of your vars are from.

Comment: @StarWind0 Which vars are you talking about? up_from_bottom.xml and down_from_top.xml are XML animation files created in anim folder if I'm not wrong. I don't have the original code as I haven't done android dev in quite some time.

Comment: For me, all items appear at same time with the animation, but it is not working when I am scrolling

Comment: @VineetAshtekar Very nice code, is there any way to do the same with GridView?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Thanks.. n sorry.. Im an iOS dev now :P Haven't done android dev in years..

Comment: @VineetAshtekar don't worry, actually I used Recycler View instead of GridView, so I was able to use your code again.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Great! AFAIK RecyclerView is the way to achieve a grid layout.. GridView and ListView were used long before. And then RecyclerView was brought in to replace them both..

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

In my code is something like this:

```
import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.adapters.AlphaInAnimationAdapter;

....

public function populate() {
   // Get your recicleview
   rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
   rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

   // Populate your cursor with your own method...
   Cursor myRecycleItems= null;
   myRecycleItems= mDbHelper.getItems();

   //create your 
   itemsAdapter= new ItemsAdapter(myRecycleItems, getApplicationContext());


   //Finnaly apply your adapter to RV with AlphaInAnimationAdapter:
   rv.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(itemsAdapter));

}
```

You need to add dependencies to your gradle

```
dependencies {
  // jCenter
  ...... 
  your curent dependencies 
  ....
  compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.0'
}
```

Read teh doc form https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators to install it.

Comment: It does not worked for me

 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollableview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SlideInBottomAnimationAdapter(new ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(items)));

Answer (score 2):

For down_from_top.xml it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any outside libraries in **RecycleView.Adapter** on method **onBindViewHolder** use animation like in example:

```
       if (position>lastAnimatedPosition) {


        //set init transitionY to animate from it
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(holder.itemView.getHeight());

        //animate to orginal position
        holder.itemView.animate().translationYBy(-  holder.itemView.getHeight()).start();


        lastAnimatedPosition=position;
    }
```

Above code will animate from bottom every row in list. Animation will be done only once, but onBindViewHolder is running on scrolling so first scrolling of list will be with animation effect.

Very important is to initialise view to start of animation, so in example i set:

```
  holder.itemView.setTranslationY( + Y change);
```

then animation go backs to orginal position:

```
 holder.itemView.animate().translationYBy(- Y change).start();
```

If you need alpha do this that way:

```
 holder.itemView.setAlpha(0);
 holder.itemView.animate().apha(1).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scroll animation you can use `recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x, y)` inside an `onScrolled()` listener, like so:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        var layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        var displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        var xPointToQuery = displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2;

        var view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(xPointToQuery, 0);
        if (view != null) {
            // 'view' is the item that is now horizontally centered on screen, animate it
        }
    }
});
```

The above code is for a case where the recyclerview is fullscreen with horizontal scroll, but you get the idea.