# android animate recycler view first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I'm trying to do a recycler view animation on scroll, but im struggling to get it started.

Basically, the animation will happen on scroll and always on the first visible child (and only on this one). When the user scrolls the recycler view, second item should overlap the first, and the first will slowly fade out. reverse animation when sliding down.

In short, when the list scroll top for example, when the first item goes offscreen and want to change that behaviour. Instead of going offscreen, it slowly fades based on scroll dY and stay in the same position.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can add custom animators to recycler view, have a look at the link below. Its a good place to start. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer may can help you. I used code like this in my app and work smootly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714138/2971619

Hope to be usefull for you too!

Comment: This answer won't help. I know how to animate items has they appear. You can set your animation in onBindViewHolder. The problem is, the animation i'm talking about will animate items as they disappear. And it needs to be synchronized with the amount of scroll. The problem is in the last part. I have no clue how to do that

Comment: The animation is kind of a 'fade in up' animation. The animation will only occur on the first child of the recyclerView, where the view are already binded