# google plus recyclerView scrolling animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how to animate a recyclerView with an animation like the google plus app. Here I have an answer [How to animate recyclerview on scroll like Google plus/Google newsstand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181307/how-to-animate-recyclerview-on-scroll-like-google-plus-google-newsstand) but I am having issues with the context and the "last position" thing, he says make a field but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Your content here

        setAnimation(holder.itemView);
}


private void setAnimation(ViewHolder holder) {
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationX", initialValue, finalValue)
                    .setDuration(1000)
                    .start();
        }
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8ifO1m9g_Q&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=49) for further information