# How to hide Items on recyclerview scrollbar gradually

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-animation

How I can hide Items on recyclerview scrollbar gradually

I want like this *Image*

[image]

*Tool Bar*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/posts_toolbar"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <com.salah250.forvo.Funcations.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/posts_title"
        android:textColor="@color/posts_title"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

*Activity Posts*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/posts_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Posts.PostsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_posts" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I looked before I could post here and I could not find any topics talking about it at all, I hope to get some ideas for doing that.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181307/how-to-animate-recyclerview-on-scroll-like-google-plus-google-newsstand

Comment: @udiboy1209 ok I'll try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put gradient image in front of your `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/posts_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Posts.PostsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_posts" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_posts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/gradient"/>

    <FrameLayout/>            

</LinearLayout>
```

`@drawable/gradient.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
    android:startColor="#302e43" />

</shape>
```

Then also add empty view with height of gradient to the header of your `RecyclerView` so topmost item will be not faded